# Wait for firebase.auth initialization before reading another function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new with firebase and javascript.

**My project:** Build a private messaging app. To do that, I want to define a sub collection in firestore for private messaging using the current user id and the destination user id.

Here is the function that allows this:

```
// generate the right SubCollection depending on current User and the User he tries to reach
function dmCollection(toUid) {

  if (toUid === null) {
    // If no destination user is definer, we set it to the below value
    toUid = 'fixed_value';
  };
  const idPair = [firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, toUid].join('_').sort();
  return firebase.firestore().collection('dms').doc(idPair).collection('messages');
};
```

**My problem:** I want to use the `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` attribute, but it looks like the function is not waiting for `firebase.auth` initialization. How can I fix this problem?

**Additional information:**
I have two functions that are calling the first one (`dmCollection`):

```
// retrieve DMs
function messagesWith(uid) {
  return dmCollection(uid).orderBy('sent', 'desc').get();
};


// send a DM
function sendDM(toUid, messageText) {
  return dmCollection(toUid).add({
    from: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
    text: messageText,
    sent: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
};
```

Comment: you can use async await !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem ("it looks like the function is not waiting for `firebase.auth` initialization"), you have two possible solutions:

#### Solution 1: Set an observer on the `Auth` object

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), you can set an observer on the `Auth` object with the [`onAuthStateChanged()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#on-auth-state-changed) method:

> By using an observer, you ensure that the `Auth` object isn't in an
>   intermediate state—such as initialization—when you get the current
>   user.

So you would modify your code as follows:

```
// retrieve DMs
function messagesWith(uid) {
  return dmCollection(uid).orderBy('sent', 'desc').get();
};


// send a DM
function sendDM(toUid, messageText) {
  return dmCollection(toUid).add({
    from: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
    text: messageText,
    sent: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
};

// generate the right SubCollection depending on current User and the User he tries to reach
function dmCollection(toUid) {

  if (toUid === null) {
    // If no destination user is definer, we set it to the below value
    toUid = 'fixed_value';
  };
  const idPair = [firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, toUid].join('_').sort();
  return firebase.firestore().collection('dms').doc(idPair).collection('messages');
};


firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    var messageText = '....';
    sendDM(user.uid, messageText)
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

---

#### Solution 2: Use the `currentUser` property

You could also "get the currently signed-in user by using the [`currentUser`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#current-user) property" as explained in the same [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user). "If a user isn't signed in, `currentUser` is null".

In this case you would do:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  var messageText = '....';
  sendDM(user.uid, messageText);
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
  // Ask the user to sign in, e.g. redirect to a sign in page
}
```

---

#### Which solution to choose?

It depends how you want to call the function(s) based on the user `uid`.

- If you want to call the function(s) immediately after the user is signed in, use Solution 1.
- If you want to call the function(s) at another specific moment (e.g. following a user action), use Solution 2.